# "One of previously used" vs. "one of the previously used"

Tags: definite-articles

> Now you can select your username in one of the following ways:
>
> 1. Enter it manually.
> 2. Use one of the previously used

By *previously used* it means previously used usernames but I do not want to repeat *username* twice.

I am not sure if should be

> one of previously used

or

> one of the previously used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both suggested forms are not grammatical. The following forms are, but may not be very clear: "Use one [that was] previously used.", "Use one of the previous [usernames]". The words in square brackets are optional.

Try something like this instead: "Select one from the list." This assumes, of course, that there is a list of previous usernames displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the suggestions, I am wondering, is 'Select a previously used one' OK? (yes there's a list of usernames)

Comment: You're welcome. "Select a previously used one" is grammatically correct.